# Apply Coupon Expiry Time Per User

Tags: woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

Currently, the woocommerce coupon expiry works on the whole Coupon itself. If I want to make a coupon,for instance, use coupon code "**10OFF24HR**" which lasts 24 hours only for A SINGLE USER,  then I cant make such coupon. The expiry date will apply to the coupon itself, not the user. Is there anyway I can make a specific coupon last for specific time for any user ( expiry date per user ). The specific expiry date for that specific coupon will apply for that particular user. Is it possible by hooks or actions in child theme.

Comment: To make this feature is complex, as it needs to be enabled for each user separately: meaning that you should need a special dashboard with all user listed where you will enable the start time by user for a specific coupon.